# If $G/[G,G]$ is compact, then $G$ is unimodular.

Tags: haar-measure

How to prove Proposition 2.29 in page no. 52 of the book " A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis (2nd edition)" by G.B. Folland which states that:

If $G/[G,G]$ is compact, then $G$ is unimodular.

Note: A proof is provided but I am unable to grasp it.

Comment: Compact groups are unimodular and the modular function is constant $1$ on $[G, G]$ should give the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is me rewriting Folland's argument.

The unimodular map is $\Delta: G \to (0,\infty)_\times$.  Notice that $[G,G] \subset \text{ker}(\Delta)$ because $\Delta([x,y]) = [\Delta(x),\Delta(y)] = 1$.  Thus this induces a map $\tilde \Delta:G/[G,G] \to (0,\infty)_\times$ such that $\tilde\Delta([G,G]x) = \Delta(x)$.  Since $G/[G,G]$ is compact, the range of $\tilde\Delta$ is compact.  And the only compact subgroup of $(0,\infty)_\times$ is $\{1\}$.